# Deshabilitar botón a una hora especifica

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, laravel

Mi problema es que tengo un botón el cual debe de habilitarse a las 8:00 y deshabilitarse a las 8:10, después, habilitarse a las 9:00 y habilitarse a las 9:10. 
¿Cómo puedo programar esto en PHP?

Comment: Que tal laurg, bienvenido... Muéstranos que es lo que llevas hecho hasta ahora, no podremos ayudarte si no subes tu código

Comment: tendrias que hacerlo con JS es creo que la manera mas sencilla

Answer (score 1):

Tu problema se puede solucionar con javascript, con PHP no es posible, ya que PHP requiere ejecución para realizar alguna acción:

Si trabajamos con Javascript quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```js
window.setInterval(
    function(){
      var d = new Date();
      var hour = d.getHours()+':'+d.getMinutes()
      let hoursActive = ['14:30', '14:35', '14:40', '14:45', '14:50']
      
      if(hoursActive.includes(hour)){
        document.getElementById('btn').style.display = 'block';
      }else{
        document.getElementById('btn').style.display = 'none';
      }
  }
,2000);
```

```html
<button id="btn">Botón</button>
```

> Como podrás ver, en este ejemplo estamos ejecutando la función cada 2
>   segundos.

Declaramos y almacenamos los elementos del array, nos sirve para mostrar el botón en horas específicas.

```
let hoursActive = ['14:30', '14:35', '14:40', '14:45', '14:50']
```

Luego hacemos una comparación con la variable `hour`, que ya tiene la hora y minuto actual.